# Database dump without revisions?

Tags: 8, database, drush, entities

Are there methods to exclude revision data in a database dump?

The purpose would be to reduce the file size for developers that want a db dump for local development.

I know that `drush sql-dump` has an option to exclude data from some tables with `--structure-tables-key` or `--structure-tables-list`. But is it safe to simply omit data from revision tables?

Comment: wonder if you found an answer. I did this using a structure-tables and exluded _revisions tables. and it worked ok but the db/content was I think missing content and not reliable for testing. I think once revisions are enabled, latest content get saved in the revision tables and excluding those will result in incomplete content.

Comment: I think I gave up on this one. But a possible idea would be to install a clone site locally, run a script to delete revisions, and then export again. Possibly this could be part of `drush sql:sanitize`.

Comment: I don't think it is possible as revision tables still need to keep default revision for each entity.